# How to append text to a div in D3

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

All:

For example I have array of string:

```
["string1","string2","string3","string4","string5"]
```

I want to add all of them into a div with 
 separate them like:

```
<div>
string1<br>
string2<br>
string3<br>
string4<br>
string5
</div>
```

I wonder how to do it with D3? I am thinking use selectAll()...data()...enter().append(), but I do not know how to append this.

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Data binding in `d3` is about **appending an element** to the dom for each item in your data.  What you are asking for, though, is how do I get one element with my strings separated by  a `<br/>`:

```
  var arr = ["string1","string2","string3","string4","string5"];
  d3.select('body')
    .append('div')
    .html(arr.join('<br/>'));
```

A more `d3`ish way to get the same appearance is (but this gives you a div per string):

```
  var arr = ["string1","string2","string3","string4","string5"];

  d3.select('body')
    .selectAll('div')
    .data(arr)
    .enter()
    .append('div')
    .text(function(d){
      return d;
    });
```

A third approach is to use `<span>`s:

```
d3.select('body')
    .selectAll('span')
    .data(arr)
    .enter()
    .append('span')
    .text(function(d){
      return d;
    })
    .append('br');
```

Here's an example with both approaches:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script> 
      var arr = ["string1","string2","string3","string4","string5"];
      d3.select('body')
        .selectAll('div')
        .data(arr)
        .enter()
        .append('div')
        .text(function(d){
          return d;
        });
        
      d3.select('body')
        .append('div')
        .html(arr.join('<br/>'))
        
      d3.select('body')
        .selectAll('span')
        .data(arr)
        .enter()
        .append('span')
        .text(function(d){
          return d;
        })
        .append('br');

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks, so this means I can not use D3 directly append text to one element?

Comment: @Kuan, the data binding is all about an element (or group of elements) per datum.  See update that use a `<span>`.

Answer (score 1):

you should appendChild to the div;

try something like this(this is pure js !!!):

```
var myArray=["string1","string2","string3","string4","string5"];
var test = document.querySelector(".test")
myArray.forEach(function(x){
var textnode = document.createTextNode(x);
test.appendChild(textnode )
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/maio/m3sqjjb3/